# Using GUIDs in Kendo UI Grids

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm working with a Kendo UI grid in asp.net mvc, where I have a model containing several properties. One of its properties (Id) is a Guid. Whenever I try to create a new row in my grid, entering all details (Id is automatically generated by a backend server) and press "Update", I get an error saying "The Id field is required". Is there a way to get around this?

I suspect the Guid-type to be the one causing trouble here.
Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ToolModel>()
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.Displace);
          columns.Bound(p => p.FishingNectOd);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Length);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Model);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Supplier).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(p => p.TagId);
          columns.Bound(p => p.ToolOd);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Type);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Weight);
          columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
      })
      .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("ToolPopUpTemplate"))
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .Scrollable()
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:500px;" })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .PageSize(10)
          .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
          .Model(model => model.Id(toolModel => toolModel.Weight))
          .Create(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Create", "ToolManagement"))
          .Read(read => read.Action("EditingPopup_Read", "ToolManagement"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "ToolManagement"))
          .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "ToolManagement"))
      ))
```

Template:

```
@using Services.Models.Tool
@model ToolModel

<div class="editor-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Displace))
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Displace))
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.FishingNectOd))
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FishingNectOd))
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Length))
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Length))
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Model))
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Model))
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name))
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name))
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Supplier))
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Supplier))
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.TagId))
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TagId))
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.ToolOd))
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ToolOd))
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Type))
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Type))
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @(Html.LabelFor(model => model.Weight))
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @(Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Weight))
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public class ToolManagementController : Controller
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger("ToolManagementController.class");
    public ToolServiceClient ToolService { get; set; }

    public ToolManagementController()
    {
        try
        {
            ToolService = new ToolServiceClient();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Error(e);
        }
    }

    // GET: ToolManagement
    public ActionResult Tools()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult EditingPopup_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        ToolContract[] list = ToolService.GetTools();
        return Json(list.ToDataSourceResult(request));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EditingPopup_Create([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ToolModel tool)
    {
        if (tool != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ToolService.CreateTool(new ToolContract
            {
                Displace = tool.Displace,
                FishingNectOD = tool.FishingNectOd,
                Length = tool.Length,
                Model = tool.Model,
                Name = tool.Name,
                Supplier = tool.Supplier,
                TagId = tool.TagId,
                ToolOD = tool.ToolOd,
                Type = tool.Type,
                Weight = tool.Weight

            });
        }

        return Json(new[] { tool }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EditingPopup_Update([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ToolModel tool)
    {
        if (tool != null && ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ToolService.UpdateTool(new ToolContract
            {
                Displace = tool.Displace,
                FishingNectOD = tool.FishingNectOd,
                Length = tool.Length,
                Model = tool.Model,
                Name = tool.Name,
                Supplier = tool.Supplier,
                TagId = tool.TagId,
                ToolOD = tool.ToolOd,
                Type = tool.Type,
                Weight = tool.Weight,
                Id = tool.Id
            });
        }

        return Json(new[] { tool }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EditingPopup_Destroy([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, ToolModel tool)
    {
        if (tool != null)
        {
            ToolService.DeleteTool(tool.Id);
        }

        return Json(new[] { tool }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
    }

}
```

And finally, the model

```
public class ToolModel
{
    private ToolContract _toolContract;

    public ToolModel(ToolContract toolContract)
    {
        ToolContract = toolContract;
    }

    public ToolModel()
    {
    }

    private ToolContract ToolContract
    {
        get { return _toolContract ?? (_toolContract = new ToolContract()); }
        set { _toolContract = value; }
    }


    public double? Displace
    {
        get { return ToolContract.Displace; }
        set { ToolContract.Displace = value; }
    }


    public double? FishingNectOd
    {
        get { return ToolContract.FishingNectOD; }
        set { ToolContract.FishingNectOD = value; }
    }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public Guid Id
    {
        get { return ToolContract.Id; }
        set { ToolContract.Id = value; }
    }

    public double? Length
    {
        get { return ToolContract.Length; }
        set { ToolContract.Length = value; }
    }

    public string Model
    {
        get { return ToolContract.Model; }
        set { ToolContract.Model = value; }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return ToolContract.Name; }
        set { ToolContract.Name = value; }
    }

    public string Supplier
    {
        get { return ToolContract.Supplier; }
        set { ToolContract.Supplier = value; }
    }

    public string TagId
    {
        get { return ToolContract.TagId; }
        set { ToolContract.Supplier = value; }
    }

    [Display(Name = "Outer Diameter")]
    public double? ToolOd
    {
        get { return ToolContract.ToolOD; }
        set { ToolContract.ToolOD = value; }
    }

    public string Type
    {
        get { return ToolContract.Type; }
        set { ToolContract.Type = value; }
    }

    public double? Weight
    {
        get { return ToolContract.Weight; }
        set { ToolContract.Weight = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's required because it's a value type and all value types are required "by default". Therefore you need to assign it a value before posting the results. If you say you're generating the GUID in code, when you add a row, automatically add the value of empty GUID: `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`. You'll overwrite the value anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved by adding a default value to the ID-field in the grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<ToolModel>()
      .Name("grid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(p => p.Id);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Displace);
          columns.Bound(p => p.FishingNeckOd);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Length);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Model);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Name);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Supplier).Width(150);
          columns.Bound(p => p.TagId);
          columns.Bound(p => p.ToolOd);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Type);
          columns.Bound(p => p.Weight);
          columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(180);
      })
      .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
      .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("ToolPopUpTemplate"))
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .Scrollable()
      .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:500px;" })
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
          .Ajax()
          .PageSize(10)
          .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
          .Model(model =>
          {
              model.Id(toolModel => toolModel.Id);
              model.Field(id => id.Id).DefaultValue(Guid.NewGuid());
          } )
          .Create(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Create", "ToolManagement"))
          .Read(read => read.Action("EditingPopup_Read", "ToolManagement"))
          .Update(update => update.Action("EditingPopup_Update", "ToolManagement"))
          .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("EditingPopup_Destroy", "ToolManagement"))
      ))
```